# Chrome pages won't stop "loading" randomly, even after all HTTP requests have finished

Tags: google-chrome

From time to time (like, the 1 % of all the web pages I visit) the "loading" indicator never stops spinning, even after all HTTP requests have finished. That continues happening even after hitting the "stop" button. I can reload the page as many times as I like and the indicator will not stop, but if I load the page in another tab, it works as it should.

I'm pretty certain it's because of an extension, but I have dozens of them and, since that occurs very rarely, selectively disabling extensions is not a practical solution for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: The kind of answer that I expect probably involves using the DevTools.

Comment: The reason is that the some extension is not properly loading so please try by disabling extension one by one to find the extension which is not working properly

Comment: @vembutech did you read the question?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before in Firefox, so I don't think it is browser specific. I would attribute it to a page that has an embedded iframe that is performing some action, likely displaying an advertisement.

I find that disabling Ghostery/AdBlock Plus tends to resolve weird page loading issues I run into, so if you have either extension installed and reasonably trust the site you are looking at, I would recommend disabling them for a few minutes and seeing if that resolves the problem.

Hopefully that can get you on the right track. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it happens very rarely so I can't afford to disable Ghostery or Adblock; it also happens in web pages I control and that I know that have no iframes or even content that Ghostery or Adblock would block.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Escape. In common browsers, this will halt any currently loading request.

Comment: Did you read the question?